# Restricting User to have one one-to-one relationship with any one of the given models Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having two model classes named as `Leader` and `Member`, both have a `OnetoOne` relationship with User, as you can see below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    # Abstract model class for common fields in Leader and Member
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Leader(Profile):
    # attributes

    # def save(self) -> None:
    #     if Member.objects.filter(user=self.user).first() == None:
    #         return super().save()
    #     else:
    #         raise ValidationError("User is already a member, migrate it to make it leader.")
            

class Member(Profile):
    # attributes
```

But if a user is already having a relation with anyone, among both of them, then it should not be allowed to have a relation with the other one.

For example:
If a `user1` is referenced by `Leader` model, then it is not allowed to be referenced by `Member` model, if needed there should be a process by which we can remove and add user from `Leader` model to `Member` model, i.e. transferring `Profile` abstract model data from `Leader` model to `Member` model and receiving remaining data manually or vica versa.

By searching over the internet, I got to know that to solve this there is a way of raising `ValidationError`, when saving the models as shown in above code, but in my case, the admin panel is used by a non-tech guy, by using above approach there will be a error screen showing my validation error, which will be unusual for them to understand easily.

What should be the better approach to implement this? 
I am using `VS Code 1.69.1`, `python 3.10.2` and `django 4.0.3`. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can anyone help me solving this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the column "user" in Profile unique, then I believe the problem is solved.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True)
```

By the way, if the extended models "Leader" and "Member" could have the same questions/fields/columns then the best option was to delete both of them and just make in profile a column to distinguish the two because you can make also two seperate tables like this:

```
leaders = Profile.objects.filter(usertype=1) # 1=leader
members = Profile.objects.filter(usertype=2) # 2=member
```

Comment: I tried using ```unique=True```, but there is no change in it. It is accepting the user as ```Member``` even it is a ```Leader```. I tried running ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate```, so as to have no doubt, but I think this is not the solution.

Comment: And for your second answer I do have some attributes in ```Leader``` and ```Member```, which are unique, so this will not work. As if I use this, there will be a wastage of resources in setting null values to the ```Member``` specific attributes if user is a ```Leader``` and vice versa.